# How can I order folders and files based on the SharePoint file path in an Excel file?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-formula, excel-2010, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint site with folders, sub-folders, and files. I am trying to create a file directory to help people know where certain files are and what they are. I can easily download the folder/file directory from SharePoint which includes folder/file name, date modified, last modified by, type (folder or file) and the file path. Unfortunately, when you download the directory, it does not keep them in parent-child order.

Is there a way to easily sort the list using the file path so that I get a list in the correct folder / sub-folder / file order? If there is a way to do this directly in the download from SharePoint, that would be even better but I've looked everywhere and it doesn't seem to be an option.

**Example of Current Output**

1. /Bob's Folder/Project Management
2. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables
3. /Bob's Folder/Calendar
4. /Bob's Folder/Project Management/Project Banana
5. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables/Week 1
6. /Bob's Folder/Project Management/Project Banana/Project Plan
7. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables/Week 1/Best Deliverable Ever

**Example of Desired Output**

1. /Bob's Folder/Project Management
2. /Bob's Folder/Project Management/Project Banana
3. /Bob's Folder/Project Management/Project Banana/Project Plan
4. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables
5. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables/Week 1
6. /Bob's Folder/Deliverables/Week 1/Best Deliverable Ever
7. /Bob's Folder/Calendar

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint's Export to Excel feature, if your SharePoint list contains folders, the folder structure does not appear in the resulting Excel table.

Reference: [Export to Excel from SharePoint or Lists (microsoft.com)](https://internal.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9)

So you couldn't download sorted lists directly from SharePoint, but you can do it in Excel. Here are steps:

1.Open the excel from sharepoint.

2.Home-> Sort&filter-> Custom sort-> Sort by path-> OK

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know